# Should I wait for an academic misconduct notation on transcript to be removed before applying for grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, transcript-of-records

In short, I have committed academic misconduct and a notation of it will be on my transcript until Jul 2023. I currently have the option of either graduating in Apr 2023 or stay one additional Fall semester and graduate in Dec 2023. I know I messed up, but regardless of that I now have to live with it.

I still intend to pursue grad or med school following graduation. If I graduate in Apr 2023, I hope to begin grad/med in Aug/Sept 2023. As you can imagine, I will be applying to schools in late 2022 or early 2023 with this notation on my transcript. This follows the "traditional" academic path.

If I graduate in Dec 2023, I hope to begin grad in Jan 2024. I will get a chance to apply to these schools after this transcript notation is removed after Jul 2023. However, it is my understanding that the majority of grad school and almost all med school matriculation is in Aug/Sept of every year, meaning I will have less school options available to me or that I will have to wait if I do end up committing to med.

Should I wait? What are your thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: More info is needed. Some such things are only for internal consumption and won't be sent along with the transcript to other entities. Some schools, perhaps med schools especially, will ask specifically if you have been charged with misconduct and ask you for details. Some transgressions are minor. Some major. Lots of variables.

Comment: According to some other posts, it seems like if schools explicitly ask, I will be required to explain myself regardless of a notation. While this isn't a super major transgression, I'm still ashamed of it. I also know it will affect my application negatively and will be sent along with my transcript. The main thing now is for programs that don't explicitly ask, and whether I should wait for the external notation to be removed.

Comment: Why does it age off? I haven't heard of that.

Comment: I don't know how old you are, but if you are young and maybe just waiting for a year and doing something else isn't a bad option for you? We are all human and human make mistakes, so just relax and make sure it won't happen again. Making a mistake in the early career is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

I won't call this advice, but just something to think about. On the face of it, you are trading a certain lost year against a hypothetical disadvantage if/when the misconduct becomes known.

But it might not be quite that stark. Two options. If you have something useful and interesting do do for (most of) a year then the year isn't really lost at all.

But a hybrid search is also possible. Some sort of a search now, perhaps small and focused, with another search next year when things seem simpler.